# PUT request works with Postman but not with Request node module

Tags: node.js, express, request

```
var options = {
    url: 'some url',
    headers:{
       'Authorization':  'some auth'
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    json: true
};

var callback = function(err, response, body){
    ///...some nice stuff
};
request(options, callback)
```

The status code in the response is 400. 
If I make the same request using postman everything works fine.
Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Solved! I had a typo in my authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of hard to say with the details obfuscated. But 400 means Bad Request. I would check all the formatting again. I would also confirm that you have specified the PUT method in the request options.